# swift compiler error "found this candidate" after adding objective c files in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bridging-header

I have created bridging header in my swift project, for use of objective c files.

whenever I import the objective c files in my project, then my swift files showing error.
I have tried all solutions available on stack overflow bt not working.
same issue checked on GitHub bt no answer found-- https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/1066

here is screenshot

[image: check screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same. Quit Xcode & Clean the derived data solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I was getting the error above. My setup was something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let tableview: UITableView = {
        let tv = UITableView()
        tv.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds

        return tv
    }()

    func makeContextMenu(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIMenu? {

            let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            pasteboard.string = cell?.detailTextLabel?.text
        }


}
```

Can you tell what the problem is?

It was because in my `makeContextMenu` I was calling `tableview`, `tableView` ie I was wrongly uppercasing it.